# configure list of objects inside observable output

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

> Forgive the awkward question title, I'm not sure how to phrase it...

I have an observable that returns a `Form` object.

```
export class QuestionConfiguration {
    //...
}

export class Question {
    configure(qc: QuestionConfiguration) {
        // set variables...
    };
}

export class Form {
    constructor(public question: Question[]) {}
}

// lets assume this does a http call and returns an instanstiated list of forms.
let doFormsRequest$ = (): Observable<Forms[]> =>  {
}
```

And I have another method which returns configuration for each inner `question` of the `Form.questions`:

```
let getQuestionConfiguration$ = (question: Question): Observable<QuestionConfiguration> {
    // ...
}
```

I wish to create a `ReplaySubject(1)` that will be the observer of an observable that configures each of the questions with the questionConfiguration observable and only returns when all the sub questions have been configured.

Is there a way to pipe/map/whatever the first observable to return the fully configured form to achieve this?

something like:

```
// using this as an observer so the configuration logic only happens once.
let mySubject: Subject<Form[]> = new ReplaySubject(1);

doFormsRequest$().pipe(
    someOperator((forms: Forms[]) => {
        // returns the configured form after calling and modifying each question according to the output of the getQuestionConfiguration observable
        // i.e. question.configure(qc: QuestionConfiguration);
    })
).subscribe(mySubject);
```

Comment: Can you just use `forkJoin` and collect all `getQuestionConfiguration`s?

Comment: I think I have managed to do such a thing last night but have not come around to posting the solution. work deadlines beckon.